# Reading JSON from file to GSON

Tags: android, json, gson

I'm trying to load .json file to GSON to deserialize.

```
File versionfile = new File(getApplicationInfo().dataDir + "/version.json");
    if (versionfile.exists()){
        Gson versionString = new Gson();
        try {
            JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(new FileReader(versionfile));
            Integer version = versionString.fromJson(reader, Integer.class);
            tabsVersion.setText(version);
        }
        catch (Exception e){} // Nothin to catch, checked before.
    }
```

But Android Studio want to use JsonReader from android.utils, giving error "Cannot resolve method fromJson". I cannot find a way to force using JsonReader from GSON lib.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `import` statements.

At the top of the file you should see something like this.

```
package com.example.app    

import android.util.JsonReader
import com.google.gson.Gson

...
```

Change the `JsonReader` import from `android.util.JsonReader` to `com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader`.

---

These imports are usually added automatically by Android Studio when you press <kbd>return</kbd> after typing the name of a class you have yet to import. A context menu should show up as you are typing the class name; make sure you scroll down to the correct import statement before you press <kbd>return</kbd>. [Here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-optimizing-imports.html) is more information on using auto import in Android Studio (and Intellij IDEA) if you're interested.

Comment: Works as a charm.